# cannot select row of jtable after adding colors even with table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true)

Tags: java, colors, jtable, selection

I have added colors to some columns of my JTable and I am no longer able to select a row by clicking on one cell of the JTable, I was able to do so right before adding colors to the columns of my JTable, I have tried using table.setRowSelectionAllowed()=true but that did not work. I have used table.setRowSelectionAllowed()=true both inside and outside the table constructor method as you can see below

```
                String[] columnNames = { "MethodID", "MethodName", "RequirementID", "RequirementName", "ClassID", "ClassName",
            "Gold", "Subject", "OwnerClass T", "Owner Class N", "Owner Class E", "# caller methods",
            "# caller methods T", "#caller methods N", "#caller methods E", "# caller classes",
            "# caller classes T", "#caller classes N", "#caller classes E", "# callee methods",
            "# callee methods T", "#callee methods N", "#callee methods E", "# callee classes",
            "# callee classes T", "#callee classes N", "#callee classes E", "CalleePrediction", "CallerPrediction",
            "Callers", "Callees"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    table = new JTable(model) {
        // Determine editor to be used by row
        public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
            int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

            if (modelColumn == 29 && row < methodtraces2.size())
                return editors1.get(row);
            if (modelColumn == 30 && row < methodtraces2.size())
                return editors3.get(row);
            /*
             * if (modelColumn == 31 && row < methodtraces2.size()) return
             * editors3.get(row); if (modelColumn == 32 && row < methodtraces2.size())
             * return editors4.get(row);
             */

            else
                return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
        }



        @Override
           public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                 int row, int column) {
              JLabel label = (JLabel) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
              if (column==OwnerClassT || column==OwnerClassN || column==OwnerClassE) {
                 label.setBackground(Color.pink);
              } else  if (column==CallerMethodsNumber || column==CallerMethodsT ||column==CallerMethodsN || column==CallerMethodsE) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                  } 
              else if(column==CallerClassesNumber || column==CallerClassesT || column==CallerClassesN || column==CallerClassesE) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.pink);
                  } 
              else if (column==CalleeMethodsNumber || column==CalleeMethodsT || column==CalleeMethodsN ||column==CalleeMethodsE) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                  } 
              else if (column==CalleeClassesNumber || column==CalleeClassesT || column==CalleeClassesN ||column==CalleeClassesE) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.pink);
                  } 
              else if (column==CalleePrediction || column==CallerPrediction ) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                  } 
              else if (column==Callers || column==Callees ) {
                     label.setBackground(Color.pink);
                  } 
              else {

                  label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
              }
              table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
              return label;
           }
    };

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(14).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(15).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(16).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(17).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(200);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(200);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(200);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setPreferredWidth(200);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(18).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(19).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(20).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(22).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(23).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(24).setPreferredWidth(150);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(25).setPreferredWidth(150);

    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

this is what my table looks like after adding setForeground

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDuc7.png)

Comment: How do you get the variable 'table'? Looks like you skipped something.

Comment: Applying a global config property inside a cell render is incorrect. Try changing it.

Comment: i also tried it outside the table constructor, I have just added more code

Comment: BTW, you fill your cells with JLabel's. As far as I remember, they are not selectable.

Comment: what do you recommend using instead of Jlabels then, I want the entire row to be selected once I click on a cell

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your code properly. See answer below.

Comment: DefaultCellRenderor does not exist in java unless you meant something else, try typing it into eclipse nothing comes up, I posted an image of what I get after using setForeground in my code everything is teh same color and the writing is kind of foggy

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    {
       Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
       setForeground(Color.blue); 
       return c;
   }
}
```

Try using **setForeground** method inside your cell render.

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(//column index//);
column.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRender());
```

Comment: I get the error DefaultCellRenderor cannot be resolved to a type, are you sure it is supposed to extend DefaultCellRenderor?

Comment: DefaultCellRenderor does not exist in java unless you meant something else, try typing it into eclipse nothing comes up, I posted an image of what I get after using setForeground in my code everything is teh same color and the writing is kind of foggy

Comment: DefaultTableCellRenderer is a class. TableCellRenderer is an interface judging from documentation.